# FitNesse: How to test SOAP web service?

Tags: soap, fitnesse

I am new to FitNesse acceptance testing. My requirement is to test a SOAP web service with FitNesse. I installed `fitnesse-standalone.jar` and am able to run simple calculation tests.

I read that by using `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures`, we can test the SOAP web services.

I‘ve downloaded the `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures-2.7.0.jar`. I don't where should I place the `.jar` file in my existing FitNesse software folder? I tried creating a folder with fixtures inside `FitnesseRoot` and placing the `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures-2.7.0.jar` inside of it.

I wrote a script, but it's not working:

```
 !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} 
 !path C:/Fitnesse/fitnesse-standalone.jar
 !path fixtures/*.jar
 !path 
 C:/Fitnesse/FitnesseRoot/fixtures/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures-2.7.0.jar
 !path fixtures/*

 |Import|
 | nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim|

 !|XmlHttpTest              |
 |script|xml http test      |
 |post  |mypostbody         |
 |to    |myserviceurl       |
 |check |response|status|200|
 |show  |response           |
```

What is the working code/script to test SOAP web services using `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is not separately downloading all components (finesse-standalone, hsac-fitnesse-fixtures, etc) but to downloaded the package containing it all fully setup (the standalone zip in the project) from the project's releases page in GitHub. For the current release it can be found at: https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/releases/download/2.7.1/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures-2.7.1-standalone.zip

The [releases page](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/releases/latest) contains (minimal) instructions how to use it:

> To get started by running some sample tests (if you have a Java
>   runtime installed):
>
> - just download the standalone.zip,
> - extract it and
> - run it (using '`java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 9090`', or on Windows just double clicking the jar to run the application on port 80
>     instead of 9090) from the directory where the 'standalone.zip' was
>     extracted and
> - open a browser to http://localhost:9090/HsacExamples.

A sample similar to what you post in your question can then be found at: http://localhost:9090/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost1Test

To make a similar test in a Suite (folder) of your own (e.g. SoapTests.FirstCall) you need to set up a couple of FitNesse basics:

- in the parent page (e.g. SoapTests). You need to add:

  `!path fixtures
  !path fixtures/*.jar
  !pomFile ../pom.xml@compile
  !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}`
- Add a setup page for the suite (e.g. SoapTests.SuiteSetUp) containing:

  `|Import                           |
  |nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture         |
  |nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim    |`

Comment: @Hoeben: i followed the above way.it works.but I have 2 more questions.1.I modified the HttpPost1Test code with respect to my code.it works. But when I place the HttpPost1Test in a new separate folder.

Comment: Like HTTP://localhost:9090/MySoapWSTest/HttpPost1Test. It fails. What all changes to be made in HttpPost1Test to make it work in custom folder

Comment: Added additional explanation in answer on how to make your own suite.

Comment: I created my own suite as suggested above.but i was facing an error :Table has 3 header columns, but row 2 only has 3 columns. My row 2 is |post|mypostbody|to|myserviceurl |

Comment: Any chance you kept the line `!|XmlHttpTest                          |` from your question in the new page? Try removing that.

Comment: That was the only way I could reproduce the error. Can you add the entire page to your question?